# Scope variables in spring/mybatis maps

Tags: java, spring, mybatis

I have a conversationScope.myVar="myValue" variable;

I would like to use it inside a mybatis map such as,

```
select col1, col1, conversationScope.myVar as ScopeVar
from table1;

desired result

col1  col2  ScopeVar

xxxx  xxxx   myValue

yyyy  yyyy   myValue

...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MyBatis does support dynamic SQL in the nature you need.  The big trick, is to use ${variable} instead of #{variable}.  Just be careful, it leaves you susceptible to SQL injection attacks.  When using # MyBatis uses PreparedStatements to avoid SQL injection, and then

So take for example example, you had a Mapper interface with method.

```
ComplexObject selectSomeObject(@Param("columnName") String columnName);
```

Your SQL map could use the parameter in part of the actual select code.

i.e.

```
<select id="selectSomeObject" resultType="someObject"> 
    select t1.column as ${columnName}    
    from table1 t1
 </select>
```

If you need a global variable, check out this question.  [MyBatis - defining a global parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8392741/mybatis-defining-a-global-parameter/8422082#8422082)

Comment: Great.  Thank You very much!  I am using an internal value, not a user supplied value