# MyBatis - defining a global parameter

Tags: java, parameters, global, mybatis

First the problem: I'm using XML-defined queries and the SQL contains database name as part of a table name. For example: `SELECT * from mydb.bar`. Unfortunately, databases are created/named all over the place and `mudb` part is really dynamic and can change at any moment. So I wanted to replace it with a property so it would look like `SELECT * FROM ${dbname}.bar` and then I defined the following section in  mybatis-config.xml:

```
<properties>
    <property name="dbname" value="mydb"/>
</properties>
```

But when I run the query `${dbname}` evaluates to null. Same happens if I define this property in the properties file. I would hate to pass this as part of the each call parameters since this is truly a global property. Can this be done? And if yes - how?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can!  This is kind of a weird undocumented feature maybe.  When building your Configuration object, do something like this.  (org.apache.ibatis.session.Configuration)

```
configuration.getVariables().put("global_param", "123");
```

Then in your XML map, you can reference.

```
    select * from ${global_param}
```

Comment: Thanks!. Unfortunately I'm using Spring to abstract MyBatis and all my configurations are defined in applicationContext.xml. I wonder though if these variables are exposed and can be set through XML configuration in applicationContext.xml, going to look into this

Comment: It looks like it should work.  I looked at source code for SqlSessionFactoryBean, it appears to set the variables to the be properties.  I haven't work with the spring integration, but I'd try debugging the buildSqlSessionFactory method in SqlSessionFactoryBean to make see where it is loading the properties.

Comment: The properties passed to 'SqlSessionFactoryBean.setConfigurationProperties()' get set as variables in the MyBatis Configuration. You should be able to create a Properties in Spring xml and use it when configuring the factory bean.

Comment: Does know anyone if there are any way for adding variables per environment and use it in the mappers?

Comment: Can we use in interceptor ?

Comment: For anyone use mybatis-plus, you can try `mybatis-plus.configuration.variables`.

Comment: @egemen yes can use in interceptor. This can work with spring maybtis also

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue using Spring+MyBatis, and solved it by setting 'configurationProperties' using my Spring XML definition for sqlSessionFactory.  My example below shows how to set a custom global property named 'encryptionKey', with a value which you can either hard-code in the XML file, or load from an external file using the context:property-placeholder tag (as below).

```
<context:property-placeholder location="/WEB-INF/spring/config-datasource.properties" />

<beans:bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
    <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <beans:property name="typeAliasesPackage" value="com.example.model" />
    <beans:property name="configurationProperties">
        <beans:props>
            <beans:prop key="encryptionKey">${jdbc.encryptionKey}</beans:prop>
        </beans:props>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

Answer (score 2):

I was using an XML configuration but not Spring and set a property inside the Configuration object but discovered that had to be done before the mapper files are loaded (see [here](http://mybatis-user.963551.n3.nabble.com/global-variables-td3602090.html)).  I abandoned the Configuration object approach and went with this approach, which worked for me:

```
  Reader reader = Resources.getResourceAsReader("..../mybatis-config.xml");
  Properties properties = new Properties();
  properties.setProperty("dbname", "mydb");
  SqlSessionFactory.factory = new SqlSessionFactoryBuilder().build(reader, "development", properties);
```

Then, as Andy Pryor posted, use `select * from ${dbname}` in the XML mapper.