# Mybatis how to dynamic create table sql in xml

Tags: java, mysql, spring, mybatis

Before,I use

```
<select id="queryUser" parameterType="userInfo">
    select * from uc_login_${tableSuffix}
</select>

userInfo:{
    private String tableSuffix;
}
```

and I create userInfo with tableSuffix like

```
new DateTime().getYear() + "_" + new DateTime().getMonthOfYear();
```

and now I select from uc_login_nowYear_nowMonth(uc_login_2015_12).
Now,I don't want create tabkeSuffix by myself,I want Mybatis help me to dynamic create sql in xml.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I find a method to deal this problem.
I find a question for :[question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8392741/mybatis-defining-a-global-parameter)

so,I create a util for createSuffix like

```
 TimeUtil:
 public static String getLoginTableSuffix(){
    if(DateTime.now().getMonthOfYear()<10){
        return DateTime.now().getYear()+"_0"+DateTime.now().getMonthOfYear();
    }else{
        return DateTime.now().getYear()+"_"+DateTime.now().getMonthOfYear();
    }

}
```

and I config my spring-dao.xml like this

```
<bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:mybatis-config.xml" />
    <property name="configurationProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="LoginTableSuffix">#{new com.qunar.secteam.basis.web.util.TimeUtil().getLoginTableSuffix()}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

then,I use this Param in my mybatis like this:

```
select * from uc_login_${LoginTableSuffix}
```

,so it's maybe deal my problem,but not very good