# How to change the database name dynamically in MyBatis XML file?

Tags: sql, spring-boot, mybatis, ibatis, spring-mybatis

I am using Spring Boot with MyBatis. I have the following query in one mapper XML file.

```
<select id="someFunction" resultMap="someResultMap">
    SELECT *
    FROM p LEFT JOIN anotherDatabase.table AS q ON p.id = q.id
</select>
```

Actually "anotherDatabase" is hard-coded in my query because I do NOT want to add another data source for only this query. But how can I make this "anotherDatabase" name dynamically (maybe configure it in some properties file) as it may change in different environment deployed?

Comment: I am not familiar with myBatis, but is it possible to use java configuration instead of xml?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MyBatis - defining a global parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8392741/mybatis-defining-a-global-parameter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though ugly solution, you can use a parameter: not a traditional JDBC/SQL parameter `#{schema}` but a direct parameter `${schema}`. See the dollar sign ($) there?

When using a direct parameter `${param}` you can insert whatever you want into the SQL. Even a entire whole SQL statement if you wish. Use it with care and **only as a last resort**.

Please carefully consider this insertion of direct parameters into the SQL is susceptible of **SQL injection**. You need to carefully control the value of the `schema` property/parameter, so it does not come from the user or any external source. If you do it like this, it will be safe to use.

However, a cleaner solution is to use a separate datasource. The only drawback is you may need to enable two-phase commit if you need transactions that emcompass tables from both datasources.